# Read one column values and update n columns of another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I currently have a SharePoint list with a column called body filled with email body.

Example, I send an email to the list with the following details in the email body.

Name: Adam

Age: 24

Country: Canada

Those details will then be saved as multiple lines of text in the list column body. Is there any way for me to extract name, age and country from the column body and insert it into another list where name, age and country will each be their own column? I only have SharePoint Designer and do not have access to the server for backend coding.

Comment: What the columns of the list receiving the e-mail? Are the name, age and country saved in a single record or are they separated by multiple records?

Comment: they are saved in a cloumn called body

Answer (score 0):

To provide details on Boland's e-mail I suggest you do the following:

1. Provide a delimiter for the data that will be saved in the body column. (eg. | or ;, so it will look something like Name: Adam | Age: 24 | Country: Canada
2. Create a SharePoint Designer Workflow like what Boland mentioned, to fire every time an item is added  in your list.
3. What the workflow does is the following:

   - Create three variables (for your example) which will hold the values for Name, Age and Country
   - Use the delimiter together with the Substring action to get the values for Name, Age and Country to assign it to the variables you created.
   - Call the Create List Item action and pass the three workflow variables you created

Let me know if you need more details so I can clarify my answer more.